# Spyder showing two equal images

Tags: python, image, spyder

I'm using Spyder to process image. I'm making two steps:

1) transform input image in black and white (grayscale);

2) putting more brightness (sum one constant to the pixels values).

However, when I plot in console these three images (original, grayscale and brightness), the final two is equal. 
I double check the variables and i'm not rewritting them.

Also, I saved the images and they are right! So I'm almost sure that the problem is on the Spyder console, but I don't know what is happenning. 
What should I do to resolve this?

image from spyder
(http://l.wigflip.com/Y53h2ZSw/roflbot.jpg)

image from files i saved
(http://l.wigflip.com/Cl0enwHK/roflbot.jpg)

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

file = 'gata_posando.png'

img = Image.open(file)
bw = np.array(img.convert('L'))
img_gataBW = Image.fromarray(bw)
#img_gataBW.save('gata_BW.png')
bw_clara = bw
print(bw)

pixel_claro = 0
```

iterating matrix to give brightness

```
for linha in range(len(bw_clara)):
    for coluna in range(len(bw_clara[linha])):
        pixel_claro = bw_clara[linha][coluna] + 100
        if pixel_claro > 255:
            pixel_claro = 255
        bw_clara[linha][coluna] = pixel_claro

print(bw_clara)
img_gataBW_clara = Image.fromarray(bw_clara)
#img_gataBW_clara.save('gata_BW_clara.png')
```

plotting the three images

```
f, vetor_print = plt.subplots(1, 3)
vetor_print[0].imshow(img)
vetor_print[1].imshow(bw, cmap = 'gray')
vetor_print[2].imshow(bw_clara, cmap = 'gray')
print(vetor_print)
```

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) This looks like a bug. Please open an issue [here](https://github.com/jupyter/qtconsole), include your code and also the file called `gata_posando.png` so we can reproduce it in our side. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, I actually fixed this by adding 
bw = np.array(img.convert('L'))
again just before the block "plotting the three images".